# Python web scraper using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraper, as you know everything has bee secured so I am working on this
selenium driver
which is not working

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import bs4
products = []
prices = []
orginalPrice =[]
sizes = []
open('product.csv','w')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/arcot/Documents/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.myntra.com/bra")
content = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content,features="lxml")
for a in soup.find('li', attrs={'class':'product-base'}):
    productName = a.find('h3', attrs={'class':'product-product'})
    productBrand = a.find('h4', attrs={'class':'product-brand'})
    size = a.find('button', attrs={'class':'product-sizeButton'})
    productPrice = a.find('span', attrs={'class':'product-discountedPrice'})
    OrginalPrice = a.find('span', attrs={'class':'product-strike'})
    name=(str(productBrand)+" "+str(productName))
    products.append(name)
    prices.append(str(productPrice))
    orginalPrice.append(str(OrginalPrice))
data = {'ProductName':products,'Price':prices,'orginalPrice':orginalPrice,'Sizes':sizes}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df.to_csv('product.csv', index=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

I tried debugging and I don't know why it's not comming but prices are comming, but other products are not comming I have tried. Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a way to scrape all the info with only one property, just need to take a look in the code and find it.

Gonna share a code might help to your work:

Beside webdriver, I import `Options`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

`Options` give us a powerful option to use our Chrome robot as a human like and avoid to be detected by the webpage you're scraping, just add this code:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"chromedriver")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {"source": 
"""Object.defineProperty(navigator, 
'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})"""})
```

Then, call your page like this:

```
url = 'https://www.myntra.com/bra'
driver.get(url)
```

Your page list all data and save it into a `<ul>`, so I take advantage of the `<li>` due to it has a class called `product-base`
So we save full list of products as a selenium `list`:

```
data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product-base')
```

Finally we need to pass `data` to another python `list` in order to have access to text.

```
data_clean = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    data_clean.append(data[i].text)
```

If you `print(data_clean)`, will see some annoying characters like `\n`, so let's clean it doing:

```
data_clean = [x.replace("\n", "|") for x in data_clean] #I used | but you can change
```

And that's it!:

```
print(data_clean)
```

Yields Score, likes, Product name, Description, Price, Discount and percentage:

```
'4|||2.4k|Zivame|Lightly Padded T-shirt Bra|Rs. 417Rs. 695(40% OFF)',
'4.2|||3k|DressBerry|Non Padded Sports Bra|Rs. 324Rs. 499(35% OFF)',
'4.1|||359|Enamor|Lightly Padded Sports Bra|Rs. 399',
```

I didn't print full list in order to keep the answer clean but data_clean got 50 results ready to pandas.

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"chromedriver")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {"source": 
"""Object.defineProperty(navigator, 
'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})"""})

url = 'https://www.myntra.com/bra'
driver.get(url)

data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product-base')

data_clean = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    data_clean.append(data[i].text)

data_clean = [x.replace("\n", "|") for x in data_clean]
print(data_clean)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @niveditamadhava no problem! Pls make sure to rate the answer if you consider it helps you. Thank you!

Comment: yeah but also if you dont mind @Alberto Castilo can you get the sizes also from the url, like there are size also mentioned in it

Comment: How to get the sizes data from the site @AlbertoCastilo

Comment: @niveditamadhava I see sizes are activated by hover so we need to think of another strategy. Do you mind if we connect by Telegram to solve this problem? I'm corpserules